# How do I copy multiple ranges to the clipboard?

Tags: vba

I have searched for this answer and many answers are close, but none of them are exactly what I need.

I need to copy the contents of 3 ranges into the clipboard and I've tried different methods to no avail. Below is an example of my code and one method...

```
Sub COPY_UPDATES()

Dim CopyPart1 As Range, CopyPart2 As Range, CopyPart3 As Range, AllParts As Range

Set CopyPart1 = Range("$B$2:$B$14").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 
Set CopyPart2 = Range("$A$2:$A$10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Set CopyPart3 = Range("$B$17")

Set AllParts = Union(CopyPart1, CopyPart2, CopyPart3)
'Set AllParts = Range("CopyPart1.Address, CopyPart2.Address, CopyPart3.Address")
'Set AllParts = Range(CopyPart1, CopyPart2, CopyPart3)

'Debug.Print CopyPart1 'Run-time error '13': Type mismatch
'Debug.Print CopyPart2 'Run-time error '13': Type mismatch
Debug.Print CopyPart3 'Immediate prints the value I need
'Debug.Print AllParts 'Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

AllParts.Copy 'Run-time error '1004': This action won't work on multiple selections

MsgBox "SQL UPDATES have been copied to the Clipboard." & vbNewLine & _
        "Paste into SMSS (New Query) and Execute (F5)"
        
End Sub
```

The only Debug.Print that does NOT set off an error is CopyPart3, the single cell range. Taking SpecialCells out of the other two doesn't seem to matter either. I seen other cases talk about setting up a loop, but is that something I need?

Again, I have searched and searched and just cannot find this particular solution.

I just want those ranges stacked up so I can paste them all at once. Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this manually FWIW - you'll get the same error: "This action won't work on multiple selections"

Comment: The union is not symmetrical, how would the blank cells/gaps be represented as text?
Iterate over the 3 ranges appending them to a string as needed then copy the string to the clipboard.

Comment: Copy your 3 ranges to a single, temporary range created for that purpose. Copy that range to the clipboard and delete it when done.

Comment: @Variatus, thank you. I did this but without deleting the new range when I was done. Having the last thing in the Sub be the .Copy instead of .Delete keeps the selection copied and ready to paste. I realized you meant in general to delete when I'm done, but there's no harm keeping it there in my case. I'll edit my OP with the new code and credit you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I needed using @Variatus's suggestion from the comments in my original post, which is basically copy and pasting each range into another range first, then copy that new range of combined ranges as one. Below is my new code with factors in there to clean out empty cells and format.

```
Sub COPY_UPDATES()

Dim CopyPart1 As Range, CopyPart2 As Range, CopyPart3 As Range, AllParts As Range
Dim CP2_LRow As Long
CP2_LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set CopyPart1 = Range("$B$2:$B$12")
Set CopyPart2 = Range("$A$2:$A$" & CP2_LRow)
Set CopyPart3 = Range("$B$14")

CopyPart1.Copy
Range("$B$20:$B$32").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'removes cell format on paste
CopyPart2.Copy
Range("$B$33:$B$" & CP2_LRow + 32).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'removes cell format on paste
CopyPart3.Copy
Range("$B$" & CP2_LRow + 32 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'removes cell format on paste

Set AllParts = Range("$B$20:$B$" & CP2_LRow + 32 + 1)
'below copies the 3 pasted ranges over one column to remove blanks from CopyParts pastes
AllParts.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Destination:=Range("$C$20")
'delete the original 3 CopyPart pastes to shift newly copy/pasted values with no blanks to AllParts range
AllParts.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Dim AP_LRow As Long, AllPartsFinal As Range
AP_LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set AllPartsFinal = Range("$B$20:$B$" & AP_LRow)
'last copy to clipboard to be pasted
AllPartsFinal.Copy

MsgBox "SQL UPDATES have been copied to the Clipboard." & vbNewLine & _
        "Paste into SMSS (New Query) and Execute (F5)"
        
End Sub
```